# How to connect background of one post with another with making shapes in wordpress website? I have attached an image of that

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry I couldn't express it clearly. But I have attached image to get the view of what I'm asking.[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39aGe.png)

Answer (score 1):

These are not "connected backgorunds". This is achieved by adding a triangle to the bottom of the blue section with negative bottom margin, which can be a png image or made with css (https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

If you can edit template file (I will use the image you have posted as an example) you need to edit template php file and add some style to the stylesheet.

Here is a quick sample.

```css
.blue-section, .grey-section {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  min-height:200px;
  }

.blue-section {
  background-color:blue;
  }

.grey-section {
    background-color:#888;
  }

.triangle {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  z-index:10;
  left:50%;
   transform: translate(-20px,0);
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 20px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-section">
  test
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  
 </div>

<div class="grey-section">

  test
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur kind help.